# How to pass service to an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

I currenlty have the the following basic `IIFE` in `JavaScript`:

```
var Test = (function(service){
  var me = this;
  me.service = service;
  var my = {};
  my.getData1 = function(){
     return me.service.GetData1();
  }
  my.getData2 = function(){
     return me.service.GetData2();
  }

  return my;

}());
```

What I would like to be able to do is the following:

```
var myService = new Service(); //code omitted but its a service class that gets data
var myTest = Test(myService);
```

The above does not work. The line `var myTest = Test(myService);` throws an error:

> Test is not a function

I also know that in an `IIFE`, one must pass in values because it is *immediately invoked* so the last line should be something like:

`}(service));`

I *can make this code work* if I just remove `Test` being the global varibale holding the `IIFE` and instead make it a global function with the following signature:

`function Test(service) {}`

However, I'm using an `IIFE` to try and prevent polluting the global scope. Is it possible I can still use it as I've designed and pass an instance of my `Service` later to `Test`? Or can it only be an `IIFE` if all of its inputs are resolved when it is invoked and therefore passing values is not possible (or maybe I have to make `service` a parameter on every method exposed in the `IIFE` that requires it)?

I was trying to prevent having to pass the service to each method. If possible I'd like to pass in the service instance but maybe my understanding is off so please correct me if it is.

Comment: Why the IIFE and not just a normal constructor that takes in the service? "I'm using an IIFE to try and prevent polluting the global scope" There's no difference... `Test` will still be global.

Comment: @plalx - I'm actually interested in your suggestion. The problem I've run into is when I have, `function Test(service) { this.myService = service`} as a constructor and I try to use it later like `var result = this.carservice.GetData1();` inside a method like `my.getData1`, I get a `Cannot read property 'GetData1' of undefined`. I think it's because `this` is bound to the object created and not working the way I had it. I have a workaround where I assign `this` to another variable like `var me = this`. What do you think?

Comment: @plalx - never mind, probably overthought it. Just pass in service and use it directly in the calls. No need to transfer around as mentioned below. Just using it directly in the methods after passing into the constructor works.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid polluting the global scope, you should *wrap* your code inside an IIFE, not convert your functions to IIFEs. That's useless and then most probably you can't call them.

```
(function() {
  var Test = function(service){
    var my = {};
    my.getData1 = function(){
      return service.GetData1();
    }
    my.getData2 = function(){
      return service.GetData2();
    }
    return my;
  };
  var myService = new Service();
  var myTest = Test(myService);
})();
```

Note that if you call `Test(myService)`, the `this` value will be the global object in sloppy mode or undefined in strict mode. So `me.service = service` will either pollute the global scope or throw an error. Just remove that, or maybe instantiate instead of call: `new Test(myService)`.

Comment: Just a side note, but IIFEs are mostly useful at the composition root or application entry point, but I wouldn't declare objects in there unless you are exposing a module. Right now you wouldn't be able to reuse Test anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

An IIFE will execute the function. Since your function returns `my`, you are effectively setting the value of `Test` to `my`, ie (`Test=my`). You want `Test` to hold a function, not its result. You could do something like this

```
var Test = function (someArg) {
    return function (someArg) {
        console.log(someArg);
    };
};
(Test())(12); //logs 12
```